# Can I have a MySQL succeed when a subquery fails and fail if the subquery succeeds?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database and a bunch of stored procedures.

I have a test SQL file which calls the stored procedures to check that they succeed on sample data and populate a test database with example records.

I would also like to have a set of statements which, in pseudocode, would be

```
SELECT (CALL SomeProc('invalid argument') EMITS ERROR) AS SomeProcCheck;
```

In this imaginary example, SomeProc is written as

```
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE SomeProc (arg TEXT)
BEGIN
    IF (IsNotValid(arg))
    THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000';
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO Foo (...);
END
```

I want my test database init script to verify that failure branches are being hit under the right circumstances.

Can I do this within MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [a continue handle](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare-handler.html) and gobble the error, if your call succeeds then signal an error:

```
DECLARE signalled INT DEFAULT 0;

BEGIN
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '45000'
  BEGIN
    SET signalled = 1;
  END;
  CALL SomeProc('invalid argument');
END
IF (signalled = 0)
THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000';
END IF;
```

Note the scope of the handler so it doesn't handle the second SIGNAL in case the error condition did not happen.
I think an exit handler without the `signalled` flag and subsequent test would also work, but I'm not sure whether the exit is global or just the scope of the handler... this brings me to I don't have a MySql db to test this so sorry for any syntax errors/bugs.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a version of this which captures all errors regardless of SQLSTATE? Or a range, e.g. SQLSTATE > 45000?

Comment: Look in the linked reference. You probably want: DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION

Comment: SQLSTATES are literals ('45000', '42S01', etc. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html) and grouping them into classes with comparison operators is not supported. Your only other option is DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '45000', SQLSTATE '42S01', SQLSTATE .... if SQLEXTENTION is too inclusive. Since this is a unit test you actually want a single SQLSTATE tested after all you know what error should be thrown for this test.

Answer (score -1):

I dont remember exactly the specific but using something along the lines of `start transaction and set autocommit and rollback` if something fails into your transaction